# Installing version of cunn from GitHub and using multilabelmargin criterion

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, torch, conv-neural-network

I need to use multilabelmargin criterion in torch7 to train a CNN. It is not supported by the current cunn. I have tried installing a different version of cunn, as here: [source](https://github.com/torch/cunn/issues/152)

```
git clone https://github.com/clementfarabet/cunn -b master
cd cunn
Luarocks make rocks/cunn-scm-1.rockspec
```

However, when I do, torch stops working and I get the error:

```
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cunn.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I subsequently needed to reinstall torch7 using ezinstall. How can I correctly install the version of cunn required, without affecting my torch installation, and therefore use multilabelmargin?